# Formatos http para enviar datos al servidor

Tags: angularjs, json, webservice

Utilizo

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

¿Cúal es la forma correcta de enviar los datos json para que los lea de forma correcta el WS?

```
data: {
  lat: '-33.4415275',
  lng: '-70.6517743'
}
```

Yo tengo este código, los mando mediante post y responde siempre con `false`.

parseado en header aparece asi:

```
lat=-33.4415275&lng=-70.6517743&singlebutton=
```

me imagino que debe de estar el error ahí.

Comment: ¿qué es lo que responde siempre con false?

Comment: Sucede que al enviar latitud  y longitud me debe de responder un json de la siguiente manera:                                                                             {"success":"true","data":[{"id_sucursal":"25","direccion":"Isidora Goyenechea 300, Las Condes","distancia_app_kms":"10.00000000","nombre_empresa":"Chile Pais Digital","distancia":"5.656596","activo":"1"}]} entonces en vez de eso me retorna false

Answer (score 1):

Creo que en tu caso es `application/json`.

Hay varios valores posibles para la cabecera(header) [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type).

Todos permiten enviar la misma información en formatos diferentes ya que el propósito de dicha cabecera es describirle al agente cual es el formato de la información del `body` que está recibiendo([tipo de medio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type)) para que pueda escoger un algoritmo adecuado y decodificarla.

Esta cabecera **puede** encontrarse en una petición o en una respuesta. La diferencia es quién le indica a quién el formato que está recibiendo. Una petición le indica al servidor y una respuesta le indica al cliente.

Tomando como base un objeto como el siguiente

```
{
    a: 1,
    b: true,
    c: [1, "a"]
}
```

La descripción de los valores más usados es

**`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`**

Este envía los datos serializados como si los hubieras enviado en la query de la url del navegador o en un [formulario http](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms). Este mismo formato puede ser usado en el `body` ya que es una cadena de caracteres donde las llaves están divididas por el símbolo `&`.

Esta es la salida del objeto anterior

```
POST /foo HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: xxxx
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf8

a=1&b=true&c[]=1&c[]=a
```

```js
$(function() {
  var a = {
    a: 1,
    b: true,
    c: [1, 'a']
  };

  console.log($.param(a));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**`multipart/form-data`**

Este sirve para enviar ficheros. La historia detrás de todo esto es que el formato anterior, entre otras razones, puede usar hasta tres bytes para codificar un solo carácter en caso que este no sea ASCII, por lo que para enviar información binaria en teoría podrías terminar enviando un fichero hasta tres veces más grande de su tamaño original. Esto evidentemente no es muy eficiente por lo que este formato cuenta con técnicas diseñadas específicamente para lidiar con dicho problema(boundaries).

```
POST /foo HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: xxxx
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=-------------------------
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="a"
-------------------------974767299852498929531610575
1
-------------------------974767299852498929531610575

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="b"; 
-------------------------974767299852498929531610575
true
-------------------------974767299852498929531610575

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="c"; 
-------------------------974767299852498929531610575
1
-------------------------974767299852498929531610575

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="c"; 
-------------------------974767299852498929531610575
a
-------------------------974767299852498929531610575
```

Además de los campos anteriores te puedes encontrar

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload"; filename="ejemplo.txt" 
Content-Type: text/plain 

<contenido del fichero>

---------------------------974767299852498929531610575
```

Como te podrás dar cuenta la cabecera `ContentType` está repetida pero el servidor la interpreta correctamente porque sabe que se refiere al tipo de contenido del fichero `ejemplo.txt`

**`application/json`**

Esta usa el conocido estándar [JSON](http://json.org/) y la salida es una cadena que se puede deserializar en un objeto JavaScript exactamente con la misma forma que se envió

```
POST /foo HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: xxxx
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf8

{"a":1,"b":true,"c": [1, "a"]}
```

Uno de los rasgos mas peculiares de JSON es que no permite el uso de comillas simples `'` y que las llaves de los objetos son cadenas de caracteres encerradas en comillas dobles `"`

Otros formatos populares son

```
text/HTML
image/png
application/pdf
```

[Aquí](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) está la lista completa de tipos de medios.

**Importante**

No confundir esta cabecera con [`Accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) que le dice al agente de usuario cuales son los tipos de medios que está dispuesto a aceptar. Esto sirve como parte del proceso de negociación entre el cliente y servidor para determinar cual será el formato más apropiado para comunicarse entre sí.